# All Notification Tray Items Dismissed When Opening App

Tags: 8.0-oreo

So on my iPhone the notification tray items disappear when I have viewed the message inside the actual application.  Windows Phone works the same way.  While all notification tray items for that app disappear when I open that application.  I do not like that all my notifications have disappeared.  Is there a setting for this maybe?

Right now I receive maybe 10 gmail or messenger notification emails and it dismisses all of the notifications as if I have read them all when I open the Gmail application from the home screen directly.  If I click on the notifications separately everything is fine.  This seems like very bizarre behavior to me.  I just can't open the app on my phone.

The hilarious thing is if I read one of the Gmail/Messenger notifications on my desktop it updates the notification properly and only dismisses one of the 10 notifications.

Edit: Ideally I am looking for a way to get this to prevent all notifications from dismissing from my mail application for sure.

Comment: I want them both though.  I want the notification dots and notifications in the pull down window to stay unless I have read the message or dismissed them individually.  I have been using notyfier but it doesn't work for all applications.  I have not tried Nova but I have a hunch a fundamental feature like this can not be changed with out root.

Comment: How about using [Unnotification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nasahapps.unnotification)    to un-dismiss notifications  if you accidentally dismiss them

Comment: @xavier_fakerat No.  So unless I there is a hidden setting the application doesn't actually display a dialog when a notification is dismissed by the actual application.  This is not me accidentally dismissing them this is the Gmail app dismissing all notifications when I open the application.  There are apps like Notification Manager  that give a history which sort of work except then you have to open a separate application to see notifications and the notification links don't always work corrocetly.  Unless you have used an iPhone or Windows Phone my question is probably confusing.

Comment: @beeshyams I am on a Nexus so it is definitely not a samsung device, but I am running Lineage OS so it is probably close to stock but may be slightly different.  I have been talking to some android deveoplers and I believe you can setongoing to true to get around this issue but I haven't had time to experiment with such.  Try opening the app from the home screen instead of from the notification bar.  It appears to clear all notifications  for the stock Gmail app for me.  I really don't care about the numbers so much as the fact all the notifications get dismissed when I manually open the app

Comment: @beeshyams No.  I am using Tesla+Nova Launcher on my device.  For my device it **does** clear all notifications in the notification tray when you open the app from the home screen.  If you would like I can post a video.

Comment: @beeshyams I have a 2nd Motorola device running stock android 5.1 and it exhibits the same behavior as I described.  I have removed all references to notification dot/number in my question because that wasn't the question.  It is the notification tray items that I am concerned about.  If you haven't used an iPhone or Windows Phone regularly my question likely is confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74543/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-william).